# jQuery UI Datepicker enable only specific days in array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to disable all dates in a datepicker and only enable dates which are in an array. This is the code I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/peter/yXMKC/ the problem is only May 14th shows up as enabled. The others are all disabled. Any ideas?

```
var availableDates = ["9-5-2011","14-5-2011","15-5-2011"];

function available(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) == 1) {
    return [true, "","Available"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","unAvailable"];
  }
}

$('#date').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available });
```

Comment: `$.inArray` will return the position the value in the array(starts from 0), if the value is not in the array, it will return `-1`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

$.inArray(dmy, availableDates) returns the index of the element, so when you compare with 1 only 14-5-2011 will match. Check for not equal to -1. Should work.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yXMKC/4/

```
var availableDates = ["9-5-2011","14-5-2011","15-5-2011"];

function available(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  console.log(dmy+' : '+($.inArray(dmy, availableDates)));
  if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
    return [true, "","Available"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","unAvailable"];
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to ask you if i added another date say "22-10-2014" and other dates it will not be working. It will show only the selected moth date how to handle this

Comment: Worked perfectly for me !