# Enable / Disable dates from ajax request : jquery calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There are similar questions in stack overflow , but i didnt find answer for me .

Here is HTML code,

```
 <div id="datepicker"></div>
```

JS :

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

on change the next , previous button events, i used ,datepicker option

```
 onChangeMonthYear:function(year, month, widget){         
    $.ajax( "/getdates",{year:year,month:month},function( data ) {
      // data = ['10/15/2014','11/15/2014']
   }); 
}
```

I want to enable the those dates which i got in `data`

i tried  `beforeShowDay`  which works onload , but i dont know how to enable/disable the calendar on every ajax request during change the month/year

Comment: please refer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480537/select-only-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker-date-list-comes-from-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before posting any question I prefer that you search it once then you place. please refer following link it helps, [Select only specific dates in jQuery UI datepicker (date list comes from AJAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480537/select-only-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker-date-list-comes-from-ajax)