# DatePicker Only Show Certain Dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to build a form where students can pick a date to take a class. Classes are only given on certain dates of the month. I am having trouble with implementing the advanced code that limits to certain dates. I was going off this post below to help me.

[jQuery UI Datepicker enable only specific days in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709320/jquery-ui-datepicker-enable-only-specific-days-in-array)

I started off creating a form with a simple input text box. I put the basic jquery code on and the pop up calendar worked fine.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker();
});
```

After that, I replaced the basic code and copied the code above so that it would only let certain dates be selected. I tried testing the form, and nothing happens if I click into the input box. I did test it at jfiddle and it worked fine so I am thinking it must be the way I'm implementing it or something.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
<script>
    var availableDates = ["9-6-2012","14-6-2012","15-6-2012"];

    function available(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) !== -1) {
            return [true, "","Available"];
        } else {
            return [false,"","unAvailable"];
        }
    }

    $('#date').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available });​
</script>
```

I've tried putting this in the head tag and the body tag without any luck. I'm not that advanced so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

jsFiddle for this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/szYYY/2/ .

Comment: Have you tried to put this on the end of body (or just below the input) or wrap this code on a `$(document).ready(function() { code here })` event like on the first one with its abreviated form `$(function() { code here });`?

Comment: The first code sample is wrapped in a DOM ready check, but the second sample is not.  Make sure to wrap the script in `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: As you can see in the jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/szYYY/2/ ), it works there because the JavaScript is executed after the DOM is loaded. Just wrap your code in a DOM ready check and you'll be fine. (Try to pinpoint the difference between the first code and the second, try to figure out what is different, or just work from that code and include more code to make it work.)

Comment: Check out this jquery plugin, it supports selectable and non selectable date choose.
http://jdpicker.paulds.fr/?p=demo