# how to select only specific date on jquery datePicker calender

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, datepicker

I'm using jquery datepicker calender , I want to select and enable the days only for the selected week.

[image]

here is my code

//        jQuery.noConflict();

```
    $('#timesheet_date').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        weekStart: 4
    })

 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail2"></label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="week_starting_date" name="week_starting_date"
                                            required="required">
                                        <option disabled selected>Select Week:</option>
                                        @foreach($weeks as $weeks)
                                            <option value="{{ $weeks->id }}">{{ $weeks->week_starting_date }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>

     <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" id="timesheet_date" name="date" class="form-control" required
                                                   value="{{old('date')}}">
                                            <label class="input-group-addon btn" for="date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></label>
                                    </div>
```

I'm loading weeks startind date in a dropdown box. and what I want is to select the seven days starting from the selected weeks dropdown date.

Ex: week dropdown selected value is 2015-12-31
my datepicker should enable or  the dates 2015-12-31 to 2016-01-06 other dates should readony/disable.

please advice . how to porceed

Comment: This question has already be asked see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709320/jquery-ui-datepicker-enable-only-specific-days-in-array

Comment: This question has  nothing to do with the PHP. I also see no code effort on your part to solve your own question.