# Active only specific dates in jQuery Datepicker Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to active only few dates (5, 10, 17, 25) of every month in [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) calendar. The rest of the dates should be disable. I am using just default code for `datepicker`:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#pacdate, #pay_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
  } );`
```

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709320/jquery-ui-datepicker-enable-only-specific-days-in-array

Comment: relevant question,just the opposite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742289/jquery-ui-date-picker-disabling-specific-dates