# How to enable only some specific dates from datepicker using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to enable some specific future dates as per the user input day from `Jquery` datepicker using Jquery/Javascript. I am explaining my code below.

```
<strong>Select Date:</strong>
<input type='text' id='txtDate' />
<button class="process" id="btn" onclick="duplicate();">Clean</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#txtDate" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 0,
    });
    function duplicate() {

    }
</script>
```

Here I have jquery datepicker. Suppose I need to enable all future `Monday and Thrusday` dates only and other dates will remain disabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Datepicker enable only specific days in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709320/jquery-ui-datepicker-enable-only-specific-days-in-array)

Comment: @AshayMandwarya : Those are as per dates but I need as per day.