# Get array of productvariatons in jQuery variable WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, wordpress, datepicker

I am using this `function` in my `functions.php`:

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'bbloomer_display_dropdown_variation_add_cart' );

function bbloomer_display_dropdown_variation_add_cart() {
   global $product;
   if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {

       $variations = $product->get_variation_attributes();
       echo "<script>console.log('" . json_encode($variations) . "');</script>";
   }

}
?>
```

In the console it shows this:

```
▼{pa_datum: Array(6)}
  ▶pa_datum: (121) ["17-04-2020, "18-02-2020", "18-03-2020, "18-04-2020", "19-02-2020, "19-03-2020"]
  ▶__proto__: Object
```

If I create an `array` in `jQuery` by myself like

```
var availableDates = ["17-04-2020, "18-02-2020", "18-03-2020, "18-04-2020", "19-02-2020, "19-03-2020"];
console.log(availableDates);
```

it shows is like this in the console:

```
▼(6) ["17-04-2020, "18-02-2020", "18-03-2020, "18-04-2020", "19-02-2020, "19-03-2020"]
  0: "17-04-2020"
  1: "18-02-2020"
  2: "18-03-2020"
  3: "18-04-2020"
  4: "19-02-2020"
  4: "19-03-2020"
  length: 6
  ▶__proto__: Array(0)
```

I use this function for datepicker to enable selected days:
[jQuery UI Datepicker enable only specific days in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709320/jquery-ui-datepicker-enable-only-specific-days-in-array)

When creating a `jQuery Array` by myself it works but inserting the `PHP` like beneath into it doesn't work.

```
var availableDates = <?php echo json_encode($variations); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var availableDates = <?php echo json_encode($variations, TRUE); ?>;
```

try this!

You want to replace the object with JSON, so you must add TRUE as the second parameter.

Comment: Doesn't have any effect